# Difference between "contradictory" and "contradicting"?

Tags: differences

I think they share the same meaning after checking up in the dictionary. Can they be used interchangeably?

[contradictory - the Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/zht/%E8%A9%9E%E5%85%B8/%E8%8B%B1%E8%AA%9E/contradictory)

Comment: Not really. If you need an ***adjectival*** form, stick to ***contradictory***.

Comment: No, they can't. Broadly *contradictory* is what they are and *contradicting* is what they are doing.

If *a soldier who is fighting* is too large a leap please consider *a warrior who is warring*.

Answer (score 3):

**No, they are not interchangeable.**

> **contradicting** (verb, present participle of "contradict"): deny the truth of
>   (a statement), especially by asserting the opposite.
>
> **contradictory** (adjective): mutually opposed or inconsistent.

(definitions from ODO)

So "**contradicting statements**" are statements that **contradict something else**, whereas "**contradictory statements**" are statements that **contradict each other**.

Comment: ps: contradictory is noun also.

Comment: I don't think you've attributed correctly here. The free online Oxford Dictionary is not OED. ELU uses the abbreviation ODO to disambiguate. / Questions lacking evidence of research when it is so obviously attainable are better close-voted.

Comment: @DripuraSundari I think "contradictory" as a noun is a term in formal logic, almost a technical term. It doesn't have the same meaning as here, and is not used generally. "Contradiction" is the noun in ordinary use.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth, thank you so much for letting me know, I was not aware about the different abbreviation. I fixed the post. As for close-voting, I don't think that's appropriate here. The OP stated that they checked the dictionary already and could not tell the difference between the definitions. If the OP didn't catch the difference in meaning, I think it's appropriate to ask for assistance with analysis on this site.

Answer (score -2):

They are not the same. Contradicting is a gerund. Contradictory is noun/adjective.

"To make a contradictory statement" and "To make a contradicting statement"

Consider the both statements. Former denotes that the statement while the latter is wrong statement contradicting should be used only for present participle.

Comment: *Contradicting* is a non-finite inflection of the verb *contradict*. As such it accepts direct objects and adverbs. There also exists a derived but deverbal adjective.